# How to populate a text box with value from DB

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I am new to asp.net and here I am trying to populate a single text box with a value from database.

I have created this code but not working:

```
Try
    Dim MyCon As New SqlConnection("server = servername; uid = sa; pwd =abc; database = master")
    Dim MyCommand As New SqlCommand("Select empFirstName from Employees where empid=2")
    MyCon.Open()
    Dim MyReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader()
    While MyReader.Read()
        Dim sqlda = New SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim dt As New Data.DataTable()
        Dim ds As New Data.DataSet
        sqlda.Fill(ds)
        TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables(0).ToString
        MyCon.Close()
    End While
```

Please correct the code and tell me where I am wrong.
Kindly suggest me a link if any to read more on this topic for beginners with example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample, it will work for you http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2008/09/12/bind-textbox-and-label-control-with-data-from-database.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> ds.Tables(0)

will return a DataTable

If you want to get the tablename, write this instead:

> ds.Tables(0).TableName

If you want to get value returned, write this kind of code:

> ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("empFirstName")

Answer (score 0):

This will store only the 1st row from the database

```
TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString();
```

`Row(0)(0)` indicates to get the 1st row from the 1st column

If the query is returning more than 1 rows then u need to iterate the data table and store it in a `List(Of String)` instead of an array as you don't know the number of rows returned from the query

```
Dim EmpFirstName As New List(Of String)
Dim myRow As DataRow
Dim myColumn As DataColumn
For Each myRow in dt.Rows
     EmpFirstName.Add(myRow(dt.Columns(0)))
Next
```